# Declare macro of multiple values and access it as an array

Tags: c

I want to create a macro that holds multiple values so that I can access them as an array, something like this:

```
#define Arr {1,2,3,4}

int main(){
    printf("%d ", Arr[0])
}
```

This is not working but I am posting it here to see if someone is able to modify it to accomplish my requirement. I cannot think of any other solution. Any hint is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does it have to be a macro?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and avoid macros. They are difficult to debug. use the power of the compiler insteead

Comment: How about `static const int Arr = {1,2,3,4};`?

Comment: I am given a program that must use macro for certain variables but one of them can have different values.

Comment: Why must it use a macro?

Comment: `#define Arr {1,2,3,4}` --> `#define Arr (int[]){1,2,3,4}`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Bad idea. That would copy the data to a local object for each function call.

Comment: That's an XY problem. Use a static variable, not a macro!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a macro when a regular variable will do:

```
int Arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Comment: I guess *only* a regular variable will do.

Comment: then you can still `#define MACROARR Arr` and you're done :)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the type of an anonymous array, which will allow you to access its elements:

```
#define Arr ((int[]) { 1, 2, 3, 4 })

int main(){
  printf("%d ", Arr[0]); // prints "1 "
}
```

However, there's little advantage to using macros here, since static constant variables do the same thing, in addition to being more flexible, optimizable and less error-prone than macros:

```
static const int Arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

int main(){
  printf("%d ", Arr[0]); // prints "1 "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a string literal instead:

```
#define Arr "\1\2\3\4"
```

Simple, though it works portably only for values 0..127, and those are octals there...

Answer (score -1):

How low level do you want to go?

```
#define  ARG_MASK 0x0f
#define  ARG_FILE 0x01
#define  ARG_NAME 0x02
#define  ARG_AGE  0x04
#define  ARG_LAST 0x08

Arg = input_from_somewhere(stdin);
Value = Arg;
printf( "Arg values are: " );

if( Value & 1 ) {
    printf( "file " );
}
Value >>= 1;
if( Value & 1 ) {
    printf( "name " );
}
Value >>= 1;
if( Value & 1 ) {
    printf( "age " );
}
Value >>= 1;
if( Value & 1 ) {
    printf( "last" );
}
printf( "\nArg %x\n", Arg );
```

Simple solution, although I prefer doing this type of testing inside a switch statement. Without knowing more the ifs work well enough.

Comment: Problem stated is holding several values in a #define. As I stated, how low do you want to go? Thus a simple bit mask in a macro, with a simple solution to extract values. Modern CPUs have 64bits, if the values are const then a bit mask is adequate and efficient.

Comment: Seemed like an answer to a slightly different question since multiple tokens have been defined vs using one macro. I'll upvote to offset some _maybe_ unfair downvotes, despite doubting the op wants to use a bitmask over an array (but the question is contextless, so... who knows...).

Comment: The question asked was incorrect as explained by several others. I simply offered a proper C solution, appropriately low level and exercising the strength in the language itself as well as m4. Bit masks and testing same are essential to becoming good at C. C++ not so much.